# installing ubuntu 13.10 latest problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, system-installation

I have 4 partition drive c,drive d,drive U ,drive e in my hard drive then I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on drive e which is empty .during the installation I use something else option..I make drive U: ext4 and I make drive e swap. then I click installed..after installing I can't find the two drives? help me please..

Comment: did you find it on gparted?

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu dont have drive c, d, e, ... at all - thats something for windows.
in linux (ubuntu) type "mount" in your terminal to see mounted devices... if you dont see your drives take a look in /etc/dev (terminal): "cd /etc/dev && ls -lah | grep sd" then you should see the hard drives (sda, sdb, sdc etc. - and for each partition on your hard drive there is a number: sda1, sda2, sda3, ...)

"none-root" drives usually mounted to /media/...

if your are running gnome you should have a program called "gnome-disk-utility" that could help you (this is a gui)